# print a series of numbers optimization part 1

Tags: c++, algorithm, optimization, addition

lets say you want to make a program that will print the numbers 1-9 over and over again

123456789123456789123456789

i guess the most obvious way to do it would be to use a loop

```
int number = 1;
while(true)
{
    print(number);
    number = number + 1;
    if(number > 9)
        number = 1;
}
```

before i go any further, is this the best way to do this or is there a more common way of doing this?

Comment: Why would you want an infinite loop to print the numbers?

Comment: theoretical problem common dont try to over think it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most *obvious* way would be this:

```
for (;;)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        print(i);
    }
}
```

Why you'd want to optifuscate it is beyond me. Output is going to so overwhelm the computation that any kind of optimization is irrelevant.

Answer (score 8):

Will this do?

```
while(true)
{
    print("123456789");
}
```

Comment: @Mike: Yeah, as long as it gives the same output the OP needs.

Comment: The only case where I can see this is "wrong" would be if it required that it continuously output the numbers in sequence, not all at once. That, or if print() has some side effects which are non-obvious from the code.

Comment: @Mike: Using `int`s would probably have that issue too, unless you turn off output buffering.

Comment: NO avoids the purpose of the problem

Answer (score 2):

Everyone using the `%` operator so far seems to be under the impression that ten values are involved. They also overlook the fact that their logic will sometimes generate `0`. One way to do what you want is:

```
int i = 1;
while (true) {
    print(i);
    i = (i % 9) + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, why are you trying to "optimize" this? Are you optimizing for speed? Space? Readability or maintainability?

A "shorter" way to do this would be like so:

```
for (int i = 1; true; i++)
{
    print(i);
    i = (i + 1) % 10;
}
```

All I did was:

1. Convert the while loop to a for
   loop
2. Convert increment +
   conditional to increment + mod
   operation.

This really is a case of micro-optimization.

Comment: This doesn't work. The first time through, the body of the loop prints `1` and sets `i` to 2. Then the loop increment sets `i` to 3 and the second time through the loop it prints `3`.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is based off Mike's answer but with further optimization:

```
for (int i = 1; true; i++)
{
    std::cout << ('0' + i);
    i = (i + 1) % 10;
}
```

Printing a number is way more expansive then printing a char and addition.