# print a series of numbers optimization part 2

Tags: c++, algorithm, optimization, addition

earlyer i posted part 1 and got some interesting responces

[print a series of numbers optimization part 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767916/print-a-series-of-numbers-optimization-part-1/5768809#5768809)

here is another way you could have the program print a repeating series of numbers to the screen, the goal here is to make the most efficiant/fastest algorithm

```
int series[] = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1]
int i = 9;

while(true)
{
    print(series[i])
    i = series[i] - 1;
}
```

of course ignore any extra overhead created by actually printing the number because that is not the purpose of the problem

the one boolean conditional statement (while true) is required for the infinite loop is required no matter what solution you do, so you can ignore that too

this solution uses memory for 11 int variables, but otherwise it only does one simple computation and one variable assignment per iteration.

so would this be the most time efficiant way to solve the infiniate number series problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [print a series of numbers optimization part 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767916/print-a-series-of-numbers-optimization-part-1)

Comment: @John this is apparently a followup question to that....

Comment: It will do some nasty overflow because the array is 9 elements long and you are referring to index at position 9 while actually the last one is in position 8.

Comment: What's the point of these silly questions? I could think of a million trivial problems and ask how to micro-optimize the equally trivial solutions.

Comment: Micro-optimizing this code is pointless. Most of the time will be spent doing I/O for outputting this stuff to the screen.

Comment: To echo Emile's point further - even if the output is being sent to shared memory (no disk I/O), most of the time will be spent formatting the integers.  So "ignore any extra overhead by actually printing the number" trivializes the problem to uselessness.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was a bit harsh in my response. When I first started programming C/C++, I didn't know any better and wasted time needlessly "optimizing" every block of code. I got overly eager in trying to push you away from that ugly path. Anyways, I suggest you read "Beware Premature Optimization" section in this Google Books preview: http://books.google.ca/books?id=_1uD7khOQooC&pg=PA43&lpg=PA43&dq=sutter+premature+optimization&source=bl&ots=KDhwj-i8zQ&sig=Bi8Fl1Vu0vU3Nw7P0UfGPj3JpLc&hl=en&ei=3GW_TfieKsvdgQeZxtDLBQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CBoQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false

Answer (score 2):

I would say it's not the most efficient way.

There's a multiplication involved in addressing the array. It's essentially

```
destinationAddress = baseAddressOfArray + indexRequested * sizeof(elementOfArray)
```

I think the most efficient way would be to cache the string of one iteration and simply spit out that string over and over again. I'm not up on my exact C++ syntax, it'd be something like

```
string s = "123456789";
while(true) {
    print(s);
}
```

Comment: I think that's not what the OP meant.

Comment: @Dani it's hard to tell exactly what OP meant, to be perfectly honest.